# Interacting with a new tab when clicking a button

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

So before I ask this question I think its good to understand how ive generally laid my project out, I use the page object model in my project and below is an example of my project structure

I create the page objects in this file:

```
import { Locator, Page } from "@playwright/test";

export class checkoutProcess{
    readonly page: Page;
    readonly proceedButton: Locator;

    constructor(page:Page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.proceedButton = page.locator('//a[@id="btnProceedToOrder"]');
    }
}
```

Ill use this page object in another file I've labeled as 'Actions'

```
import { checkoutProgress } from "../../Page Objects/checkoutProgress";

export class checkoutActions extends checkoutProgress{
    async completeCheckout() {
      //stuff using page objects
      await this.proceedButton.click(); //example  
    }
   

}
```

I use the actions within the spec file:

```
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";
import { checkoutActions } from "../../Actions/checkoutActions";

test.describe('Survey Management Tests', () => {
    let checkout;
   

    test.beforeEach(async ({page}) => {
        checkout = new checkoutActions(page);
        await page.goto('/');
    });
    test('Checkout', async () => { 
        await checkout.completeCheckout();
    });
});
```

So now in one of my actions I have to click on a link that opens a new tab(page) and when I try to assert anything on the new tab it fails. Im assuming my page objects are using the wrong instance of the page because the locators are accurate, and the problem lies when I write `this.page.locator('')` in the page object file.

Is this assumption correct? When I run the project in debug mode, clicking the link immediately puts focus on it so I dont have to switch tabs or anything.

when i run the debugger i see that the assertion was detected:
[image]

when i try to step over:
[image]

Comment: This looks OK at a glance. Can you share a [mcve] with your assertion that I can run? Ideally, there's a tiny sample page that helps make it all runnable. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen the assertion 
```await expect(this.proceedButton).toBeVisible();``` fails

I cant share much else due to it being confidential/work related. But to add context when I click the link on the current page, I get immediately taken to a new page, and in debug mode the asserted element is highlighted but the debugger will fail it saying it wasn't able to locate it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's enough context. "Im assuming my page objects are using the wrong instance of the page" doesn't seem right to me. These look like they're all using the same `page` instance on an eyeball--there's nothing in the code that uses anything but the `page` passed into the test case, so the problem is likely elsewhere, like the locator failing for another reason than you may assume.

Comment: @ggorlen yeah i came to the same conclusion because I tried asserting another element on the page except I added a page object scoped to the test itself

```test('Checkout', async ({page}) => { await expect(page.locator('//mylocator').toBeVisible();});
```
and that assertion failed too, but the selector is valid because like I mentioned in debug mode its highlighted, but when attempting to move forward the assertion will timeout for a cannot be detected exception.

Comment: Are you trying headful step mode to try to debug the problem? It's possible the browser isn't getting to the page you think it is (a lot of other things can go wrong on top of that, hard to guess).

Comment: @ggorlen updated the post with some screenshots but to answer your question yes im running the debugger and stepping through. Prior to the assertion, I clicked a button on one page to take me to the page on the screenshot. Afterwards it fails on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looks like you have to switch to a new tab before starting any action or checks on it. the code below may help you to do this:

```
import { Locator, Page, BrowserContext } from "@playwright/test";

export class checkoutProcess{
  readonly page: Page;
  readonly context: BrowserContext;
  readonly proceedButton: Locator;

  constructor(page:Page, context:BrowserContext) {
    this.page = page;
    this.context = context;
    this.proceedButton = page.locator('//a[@id="btnProceedToOrder"]');
  }
}
```

Then in checkoutActions:

```
  async completeCheckout() {
     const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
       this.context.waitForEvent('page'),
       this.proceedButton.click()
    ]);
    return newPage;
    // or
    // return new someNewTabPage(newPage, this.context); // if you have it as a separately described page
  }
```

And, finally, the spec file:

```
import { expect, test, Page, BrowserContext } from "@playwright/test";
import { checkoutActions } from "../../Actions/checkoutActions";
let context: BrowserContext;
let page: Page;

test.describe('Survey Management Tests', () => {
  let checkout;


  test.beforeEach(async ({browser}) => {
    context = await browser.newContext()
    page = await context.newPage()
    checkout = new checkoutActions(page);
    await page.goto('/');
  });
  test('Checkout', async () => { 
    const someNewTabPage = await checkout.completeCheckout();
    await expect(someNewTabPage.locator('//mylocator').toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you! I knew it was some weird tab switching thing. I just wasn't sure how to apply a new page with my project structure.